# Mongoose push or addToSet sometimes add twice an item into array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a server in nodeJs and MongoDB, I use mongoose for operation with Mongodb.

I really cant figure it out, why this really simple function, sometimes decides to add 2 times the same reference into the array

```
    async pushItems(itemsData) {
        try{
            /** Populate items if needed **/
            if (!this.model.populated('itemsId')) {
                await this.model.populate('itemsId').execPopulate();
            }
        
            for (const newItemData of itemsData) {  
                /** Check if item already presented in cart **/
                const existingItem = await this.model.findItem(newItemData);
                /** If item already presented in cart - increase quantity **/
                if (existingItem) {
                    logs.add_notice("Found an Exisiting Item");
                    console.log(existingItem);
                    const itemService = new ItemService(existingItem);
                    await itemService.update({
                        productQuantity: existingItem.productQuantity + newItemData.productQuantity
                    });
                /** If item is new - add to cart **/
                } else {
                    const createdItem = await this.model.addCartItem(newItemData);
                    
                    this.model.itemsId.addToSet(createdItem);
                    
                }
            }

            this.setTotalAmountNeedsUpdate();

            await this.save();
            
        }catch(e){
            logs.add_warning("ERROR CART SERVICE pushItems")
            logs.add_error(e);
        }
    }
```

the line incriminated is this

`this.model.itemsId.addToSet(createdItem);`

I already tried

`this.model.itemsId.push(createdItem);`

but I got the same problem

What I can't understand is why I cant reproduce the error, because i can maybe add 10 items into the cart and everything works perfectly and then on the 11 item the bug occur

or maybe even just at the second item the bug occur

one thing I noticed is using
`await this.model.itemsId.addToSet(createdItem);` or
`await this.model.itemsId.push(createdItem);`

the bug occur really sporadically but it still occur

I have some logs to if someone need it